# How to read time stamp data from text file using C code?

Tags: c, linux

I am Continuously data writing in text file with time stamp using c code, How to read one day / two days / one week / one year data from text file ? Below are the sample text file data.

```
20190629105716 value1:15 value2:25 value3:622
20190629105716 value1:15 value2:25 value3:622
20190630105716 value1:15 value2:25 value3:622
20190701105716 value1:15 value2:25 value3:622
20190702105716 value1:15 value2:25 value3:622
20190703105716 value1:15 value2:25 value3:622
20190704105716 value1:15 value2:25 value3:622
20190705105716 value1:15 value2:25 value3:622
```

Comment: You should decide whether it is Wednesday 3rd July or Thursday 4th July that you're looking at; the data is contradictory.

Comment: Read lines with `fgets()`; scan the date/time portion with `strptime()`, and the temperature portion with `sscanf()`.

Comment: Looks like you accumulate temperature second by second. You repeat a lot of information for each second. Are you only interested in temp at 4:00 am ? Is the format static ? Why not use a database ? First step would be to encode logically YYMMDD hhmmss ( Year Month Day hour minute second )

Comment: BobRun@ My code changed as per your suggested format : 20190704054550 Data : 80
20190704054551 Data : 80
20190704054552 Data : 80

Comment: What does `20190702105716` mean? Depending on where the data came from it may not be "number of seconds since 1970, GMT (without leap seconds)" and could be anything (e.g. number of microseconds since 2000 local time (with leap seconds)").

Comment: Brendan@ This time format 2019/07/02/ 10:7:16, By using "strftime (s, sizeof(s), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S",tm1)" function time stored in s buffer same buffer print in text file. How to subtract (7 days/ 20 days ) date and with current time please provide me any solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the issue with the inconsistent dates, Jonathan’s comment contains the solution. However, using these functions correctly isn’t trivial. Here’s a brief example of how to use [`strptime`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html) and [`sscanf`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sscanf.html) in such a scenario.

I’ve made one simplification in the following code, by mandating that each line in your input data is has a fixed maximum length. This assumption is *probably safe*, but if it is violated the code breaks badly. Unfortunately handling variable line lengths makes such code a lot more complex.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_LINE 1024

int main(void) {
    char line[MAX_LINE];

    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE, stdin) != NULL) {
        struct tm tm;
        char *temp_ptr = strptime(line, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", &tm);
        if (temp_ptr == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error parsing date at \"%s\"\n", line);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        int temp;
        if (sscanf(temp_ptr, " temp : %d", &temp) == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error parsing temperature at \"%s\"\n", temp_ptr);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        // At this point we’ve successfully parsed the date and temperature.
        // Now we can use it. As a simple example, we just print it again:

        char time_str[20];
        strftime(time_str, sizeof time_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm);
        printf("Temperature %d on %s\n", temp, time_str);
    }

    if (! feof(stdin)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading input\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This code reads the data from stdin. Change as appropriate.

Furthermore, this code uses the *current locale* to parse the weekday and month names. In general you will want to exert more control over this. Better yet, don’t rely on “natural language names” for dates at all by changing your data format. Storing dates as “Wed Jul 4 …” is only sensible for human readers, it makes no sense at all for machine reading. The only acceptable ways of storing machine readable dates are as [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (aka YYYY-MM-DD) or as [POSIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: How to read complete one week data from text file ? My text file format is 20190704105716 value1:15 value2:25 value3:622

Comment: @user2908174 Why did you not post that format in your question then? At any rate, with the information provided in this answer you should be able to figure out how to adapt the code to a different format.

Comment: konrad Rudolph@ Thanks for the reply, After my post @bobrun suggested this format so i changed my code again, My requirement is to read one week back data from text file, please provide me any solution for this issue.

Comment: How are you going to identify which week to scan, @user2908174?  That will control how you do your selection processing.  It isn't hard; you just have to think it through, carefully enough.